# Apple reject my app due to crashed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 12.2 on WiFi

Tags: ios, crash-log

I am not understanding. What apple is saying about crash. How can I resolve it. Apple is sending me crashlog report's but i am getting confused in crashlog report . What's the error in it.

Can anyone help me figure out this issue . And I already tested my app on iOS 12.2 devices. It is working fine.

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> Your app still crashed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 12.2 on WiFi
>   when we:
>
> - Launch app.
> - Logged in.
> - App crashed.
> - App crashes on lunch afterwards.
>
> We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app and test it on a device
>   to ensure that it runs as expected.

```
{"app_name":"Browser","timestamp":"2019-05-02 16:15:58.76 -0700","app_version":"1.1.4","slice_uuid":"f48d908b-0852-3c9b-9dc2-3432079b2d05","adam_id":1438432017,"build_version":"1.3","bundleID":"com.browserworldwide.browserprime","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.2 (16E227)","incident_id":"23F54364-AF5E-4DCE-9081-BE9507BAFDF9","name":"Browser"}
Incident Identifier: 23F54364-AF5E-4DCE-9081-BE9507BAFDF9
CrashReporter Key:   6e4985737224f5ec964bbc86447765995fb962e7
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Browser [17605]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/206163CB-F817-4A5E-84BA-F9A58EDAAAD0/Browser.app/Browser
Identifier:          com.browserworldwide.browserprime
Version:             1.3 (1.1.4)
AppStoreTools:       10E121a
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.browserworldwide.browserprime [6762]


Date/Time:           2019-05-02 16:15:58.6186 -0700
Launch Time:         2019-05-02 16:15:57.6501 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.2 (16E227)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010405f514
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [17605]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Browser                         0x000000010405f514 0x10401c000 + 275732
1   Browser                         0x0000000104067b08 0x10401c000 + 310024
2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8e2e8f8 0x1b8b1d000 + 3217656
3   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8d9ed38 0x1b8b1d000 + 2628920
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8d9f040 0x1b8b1d000 + 2629696
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8d9ff7c 0x1b8b1d000 + 2633596
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8da1210 0x1b8b1d000 + 2638352
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b8d84420 0x1b8b1d000 + 2520096
8   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b985fe54 0x1b8b1d000 + 13905492
9   QuartzCore                      0x00000001916dd1f0 0x1915a0000 + 1298928
10  QuartzCore                      0x00000001916e2198 0x1915a0000 + 1319320
11  QuartzCore                      0x00000001916450a8 0x1915a0000 + 676008
12  QuartzCore                      0x0000000191673108 0x1915a0000 + 864520
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b93f0534 0x1b8b1d000 + 9254196
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1e110c 0x18d137000 + 696588
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1e0a10 0x18d137000 + 694800
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1dba74 0x18d137000 + 674420
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1db354 0x18d137000 + 672596
18  GraphicsServices                0x000000018f3db79c 0x18f3d1000 + 42908
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b93d7b68 0x1b8b1d000 + 9153384
20  Browser                         0x0000000104043258 0x10401c000 + 160344
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018cca18e0 0x18cca0000 + 6368

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.0x1059480b0
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde2148 0x18cdca000 + 98632
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc32880 0x18cc30000 + 10368
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc331d8 0x18cc30000 + 12760
3   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f34804 0x193f31000 + 14340
4   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f3990c 0x193f31000 + 35084
5   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f92ebc 0x193f31000 + 401084
6   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f92de8 0x193f31000 + 400872
7   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8dd14 0x193f31000 + 380180
8   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8dbcc 0x193f31000 + 379852
9   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8ff08 0x193f31000 + 388872
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea7be4 0x18ce9c000 + 48100
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea7f48 0x18ce9c000 + 48968
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc90894 0x18cc30000 + 395412
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc485bc 0x18cc30000 + 99772
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc391ec 0x18cc30000 + 37356
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc491c8 0x18cc30000 + 102856
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc391ec 0x18cc30000 + 37356
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc39e3c 0x18cc30000 + 40508
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc424a8 0x18cc30000 + 74920
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce70114 0x18ce64000 + 49428
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd4 0x18ce64000 + 60628

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.0x105910fa0
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde2148 0x18cdca000 + 98632
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc32880 0x18cc30000 + 10368
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc331d8 0x18cc30000 + 12760
3   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f34804 0x193f31000 + 14340
4   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f3990c 0x193f31000 + 35084
5   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f92ebc 0x193f31000 + 401084
6   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f92de8 0x193f31000 + 400872
7   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8dd14 0x193f31000 + 380180
8   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8dbcc 0x193f31000 + 379852
9   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8ff08 0x193f31000 + 388872
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea7be4 0x18ce9c000 + 48100
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea7f48 0x18ce9c000 + 48968
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc90894 0x18cc30000 + 395412
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc485bc 0x18cc30000 + 99772
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc391ec 0x18cc30000 + 37356
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc491c8 0x18cc30000 + 102856
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc391ec 0x18cc30000 + 37356
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc39e3c 0x18cc30000 + 40508
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc424a8 0x18cc30000 + 74920
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce70114 0x18ce64000 + 49428
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd4 0x18ce64000 + 60628

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd0 0x18ce64000 + 60624

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd0 0x18ce64000 + 60624

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde20f4 0x18cdca000 + 98548
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde15a0 0x18cdca000 + 95648
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1e0cb4 0x18d137000 + 695476
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1dbbc4 0x18d137000 + 674756
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1db354 0x18d137000 + 672596
5   Foundation                      0x000000018dba8fcc 0x18dba1000 + 32716
6   Foundation                      0x000000018dba8e5c 0x18dba1000 + 32348
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b94bd540 0x1b8b1d000 + 10093888
8   Foundation                      0x000000018dcd56e4 0x18dba1000 + 1263332
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce6f2c0 0x18ce64000 + 45760
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce6f220 0x18ce64000 + 45600
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cdc 0x18ce64000 + 60636

Thread 6 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde20f4 0x18cdca000 + 98548
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde15a0 0x18cdca000 + 95648
2   Browser                         0x0000000104237744 0x10401c000 + 2209604
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce6f2c0 0x18ce64000 + 45760
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce6f220 0x18ce64000 + 45600
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cdc 0x18ce64000 + 60636

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: FIRAPersistedConfig
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde20f4 0x18cdca000 + 98548
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde15a0 0x18cdca000 + 95648
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc47880 0x18cc30000 + 96384
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc47d10 0x18cc30000 + 97552
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea6a04 0x18ce9c000 + 43524
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d192f00 0x18d137000 + 376576
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d143994 0x18d137000 + 51604
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d144b20 0x18d137000 + 56096
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d140738 0x18d137000 + 38712
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d192a20 0x18d137000 + 375328
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d2815d0 0x18d137000 + 1353168
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d2818c4 0x18d137000 + 1353924
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1caec0 0x18d137000 + 605888
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d2815d0 0x18d137000 + 1353168
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d2818c4 0x18d137000 + 1353924
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d13ecac 0x18d137000 + 31916
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1ccff4 0x18d137000 + 614388
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1cca38 0x18d137000 + 612920
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d13b634 0x18d137000 + 17972
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d13e64c 0x18d137000 + 30284
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d28b700 0x18d137000 + 1394432
21  Foundation                      0x000000018dbeaa38 0x18dba1000 + 301624
22  Browser                         0x00000001042cdbc4 0x10401c000 + 2825156
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc907d4 0x18cc30000 + 395220
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc3ec18 0x18cc30000 + 60440
25  Browser                         0x00000001042ba6f8 0x10401c000 + 2746104
26  Browser                         0x00000001042a68e0 0x10401c000 + 2664672
27  Browser                         0x00000001042a6728 0x10401c000 + 2664232
28  Browser                         0x00000001042a53ac 0x10401c000 + 2659244
29  Browser                         0x00000001042bfd80 0x10401c000 + 2768256
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc8fa38 0x18cc30000 + 391736
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc907d4 0x18cc30000 + 395220
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc39320 0x18cc30000 + 37664
33  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc39e3c 0x18cc30000 + 40508
34  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc424a8 0x18cc30000 + 74920
35  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce70114 0x18ce64000 + 49428
36  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd4 0x18ce64000 + 60628

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cdee93c 0x18cdca000 + 149820
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc4ebf0 0x18cc30000 + 125936
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc4e6b0 0x18cc30000 + 124592
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc4e5e4 0x18cc30000 + 124388
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc493f0 0x18cc30000 + 103408
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc424a8 0x18cc30000 + 74920
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce70114 0x18ce64000 + 49428
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd4 0x18ce64000 + 60628

Thread 9 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.network.connections
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cdebfc8 0x18cdca000 + 139208
1   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018e2b31e4 0x18e15c000 + 1405412
2   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018e2b2154 0x18e15c000 + 1401172
3   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018e2b19e8 0x18e15c000 + 1399272
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc907d4 0x18cc30000 + 395220
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc35018 0x18cc30000 + 20504
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc44fa4 0x18cc30000 + 85924
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc3b108 0x18cc30000 + 45320
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc424a8 0x18cc30000 + 74920
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce70114 0x18ce64000 + 49428
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd4 0x18ce64000 + 60628

Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.0x105953b50
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde2148 0x18cdca000 + 98632
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc32880 0x18cc30000 + 10368
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc331d8 0x18cc30000 + 12760
3   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f34804 0x193f31000 + 14340
4   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f3990c 0x193f31000 + 35084
5   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f92ebc 0x193f31000 + 401084
6   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f92de8 0x193f31000 + 400872
7   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8dd14 0x193f31000 + 380180
8   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8dbcc 0x193f31000 + 379852
9   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8ff08 0x193f31000 + 388872
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea7be4 0x18ce9c000 + 48100
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea7f48 0x18ce9c000 + 48968
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc90894 0x18cc30000 + 395412
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc485bc 0x18cc30000 + 99772
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc391ec 0x18cc30000 + 37356
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc491c8 0x18cc30000 + 102856
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc391ec 0x18cc30000 + 37356
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc39e3c 0x18cc30000 + 40508
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc424a8 0x18cc30000 + 74920
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce70114 0x18ce64000 + 49428
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd4 0x18ce64000 + 60628

Thread 11 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde20f4 0x18cdca000 + 98548
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde15a0 0x18cdca000 + 95648
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1e0cb4 0x18d137000 + 695476
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1dbbc4 0x18d137000 + 674756
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d1db354 0x18d137000 + 672596
5   AVFAudio                        0x0000000193099378 0x19300d000 + 574328
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001930c3c60 0x19300d000 + 748640
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce6f2c0 0x18ce64000 + 45760
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce6f220 0x18ce64000 + 45600
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cdc 0x18ce64000 + 60636

Thread 12 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCConnection.m-user.com.apple.nsurlsessiond
Thread 12:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018c442548 0x18c425000 + 120136
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d140c4c 0x18d137000 + 40012
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018d14af9c 0x18d137000 + 81820
3   Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2e14 0x18dba1000 + 138772
4   Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
5   Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
6   Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
7   Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
8   Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
9   Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
10  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
11  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
12  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
13  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
14  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
15  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
16  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
17  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
18  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
19  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
20  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
21  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
22  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
23  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
24  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
25  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
26  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
27  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
28  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
29  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
30  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
31  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
32  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
33  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
34  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
35  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
36  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
37  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
38  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
39  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
40  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
41  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
42  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
43  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
44  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
45  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
46  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
47  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
48  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
49  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
50  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
51  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
52  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
53  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
54  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
55  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
56  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
57  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
58  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
59  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
60  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd3204 0x18dba1000 + 2302468
61  Foundation                      0x000000018dde9da4 0x18dba1000 + 2395556
62  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc3478 0x18dba1000 + 140408
63  Foundation                      0x000000018dbc2dac 0x18dba1000 + 138668
64  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
65  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd31c8 0x18dba1000 + 2302408
66  Foundation                      0x000000018dbb6bc4 0x18dba1000 + 89028
67  CFNetwork                       0x000000018d810720 0x18d7f3000 + 120608
68  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd2f58 0x18dba1000 + 2301784
69  Foundation                      0x000000018dbb6168 0x18dba1000 + 86376
70  Foundation                      0x000000018ddfa998 0x18dba1000 + 2464152
71  Foundation                      0x000000018ddfb21c 0x18dba1000 + 2466332
72  Foundation                      0x000000018dc0ca04 0x18dba1000 + 440836
73  Foundation                      0x000000018dc0cd8c 0x18dba1000 + 441740
74  Foundation                      0x000000018dbf70e4 0x18dba1000 + 352484
75  Foundation                      0x000000018ddd10a4 0x18dba1000 + 2293924
76  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea7be4 0x18ce9c000 + 48100
77  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea7f48 0x18ce9c000 + 48968
78  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc90894 0x18cc30000 + 395412
79  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc485bc 0x18cc30000 + 99772
80  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc391ec 0x18cc30000 + 37356
81  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc491c8 0x18cc30000 + 102856
82  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc391ec 0x18cc30000 + 37356
83  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc39e70 0x18cc30000 + 40560
84  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc424a8 0x18cc30000 + 74920
85  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce70114 0x18ce64000 + 49428
86  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd4 0x18ce64000 + 60628

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd0 0x18ce64000 + 60624

Thread 14 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.0x105954c50
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cde2148 0x18cdca000 + 98632
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc32880 0x18cc30000 + 10368
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc331d8 0x18cc30000 + 12760
3   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f34804 0x193f31000 + 14340
4   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f3990c 0x193f31000 + 35084
5   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f92ebc 0x193f31000 + 401084
6   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f92de8 0x193f31000 + 400872
7   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8dd14 0x193f31000 + 380180
8   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8dbcc 0x193f31000 + 379852
9   CoreLocation                    0x0000000193f8ff08 0x193f31000 + 388872
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea7be4 0x18ce9c000 + 48100
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018cea7f48 0x18ce9c000 + 48968
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc90894 0x18cc30000 + 395412
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc485bc 0x18cc30000 + 99772
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc391ec 0x18cc30000 + 37356
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc491c8 0x18cc30000 + 102856
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc391ec 0x18cc30000 + 37356
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc39e3c 0x18cc30000 + 40508
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018cc424a8 0x18cc30000 + 74920
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce70114 0x18ce64000 + 49428
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd4 0x18ce64000 + 60628

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd0 0x18ce64000 + 60624

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ce72cd0 0x18ce64000 + 60624

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000002   x1: 0x0000000281ca4dc0   x2: 0x0000000000000004   x3: 0x000000018ce24130
    x4: 0x0000000105b633a0   x5: 0x0000000000000022   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000104a8b000   x9: 0x0000000000000001  x10: 0x000000000000002d  x11: 0x00000000000007fb
   x12: 0x00000000000007fd  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x000000008fe46000  x15: 0x000000000000008c
   x16: 0x0000000080000000  x17: 0x000000000fe00000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000104a58990
   x20: 0x0000000106879600  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000000380  x23: 0x0000000104a3c000
   x24: 0x0000000000000388  x25: 0x000000010682f800  x26: 0x0000000000000400  x27: 0x0000000281c81770
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016bde0010   lr: 0x000000010405e948
    sp: 0x000000016bddff20   pc: 0x000000010405f514 cpsr: 0x80000000
```

Comment: attach crash logs so that it will be clear

Comment: @vivekDas.   this is drive link url for crashlogs (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1--_CIWpoz1VmzxQ1XPIXG3Q7IjaNaBkH/view)

Comment: @vivekDas have you get any solution.

Comment: Not able to access your logs, attach in this question

Comment: @vivekDas.  Updated

Comment: You need to symbolicate the supplied crashlog. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html. You can also try a Testflight build on a real device and try to replicate the issue

Comment: Try symbolicating this logs first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Resolved my issue I was getting crash on my another screen and latitude and longitude values going nil when I am set Never on GPS location.